# Create tag for [control-flow-graph] and/or rename [cfg] to [context-free-grammars]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-creation

I was wondering if it would be a good idea to create a tag for [control-flow-graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph).

Firstly, it is a popular data structure used in a number of areas of computer science, especially compilers and software engineering.

Secondly, people use "cfg" to abbreviate control flow graph resulting in an ambiguity with "context free grammars" which has its own tag [cfg](/questions/tagged/cfg). I recently came across a question that used the [cfg](/questions/tagged/cfg) tag but was really talking about control flow graphs. Now there is a tag for [control-flow](/questions/tagged/control-flow), but perhaps that might not be as intuitive as "cfg"?

So I propose that we either rename [cfg](/questions/tagged/cfg) to [context-free-grammar](/questions/tagged/context-free-grammar) and/or create a separate tag for "control-flow-graph".

Numbers:
Google returns about 4.5 million results and Stack Overflow returns 311 results for control flow graph.
Google returns about 3.76 million results and Stack Overflow returns 845 results for context free grammar.

Comment: There's also a few questions in there using [cfg] to refer to .cfg files, or configuration in general (this is actually in the tag wiki, interestingly).

Comment: @JohnFlatness yes i noticed that as well. given all these issues, i really think it is worth considering a rename of [tag:cfg] into possibly two different tags and an introduction of a new tag for "control flow graph"